# sql returning 0 rows even when where clause mathches

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to execute

```
  SELECT * FROM `product_laptop` WHERE name = "Acer  Sdfsdf"
```

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 seconds.)

even though there is an entry with the name Acer  Sdfsdf` 
and name is also defined as unique key.
[image: Other name data works fine]

Comment: I would guess the value in the database only has one space between the two words.

Comment: Or maybe a newline

Comment: no there are two  - Acer  Sdfsdf

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM \`product_laptop\` WHERE name like "Acer%Sdfsdf"` bring back results?

Comment: @TejasKale is it possible that sql has new line in a column?

Comment: @chris85 hell yeah
SELECT * FROM `product_laptop` WHERE name like "Acer%Sdfsdf"
Worked like a charm how you did that?

Comment: Its a text column, sure it can have newlines.

Comment: @chris85 but I am looking for an exact match I am working with sql and php since a year and never get problem like this i am so confused why is this happning

Comment: You have some other characters in the record you are looking at in that case. You will need to clear those out. Since you are in a browser continuos white spaces are displayed as one space.

Comment: try using LIKE , and test your query in SQL tab of phpmyadmin and see result

Comment: LIKE works fine but I am not sure what happend to it if there are 2 white spaces why it is not returning the row and I can't rely on like there can be many laptops with 90% matching name

Comment: Can you show 3 examples? `Acer%Sdfsdf` Is only going to match records That start with `Acer` have anything in the middle and end with `Sdfsdf`. Are you going to have a lot of those?

Comment: @chris85 Sdfsdf is just random text basically its gonna acer predator 13
acer predator 14 etc
and the problem is i don't know hot to put %(wildcard) between a $name variable

Comment: @RishabhGusain updated answer with a regex approach below that will swap white spaces into `%`s.

Comment: @chris85 thanks  for the help  this community is awesome.This community is one of the reason why I love coding

Comment: @RishabhGusain if that works please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try `like` to get the correct data:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_laptop` WHERE name LIKE "Acer%"
```

Would that suit your needs?

Comment: sorry sir I am looking for an exact match there are possible many Acer laptops

Answer (score 1):

The `=` requires an exact match, using `like` with the `%` wildcard will give you the results you want. This won't match exact records though and will allow for all sorts of variations.

```
SELECT * FROM `product_laptop` WHERE name like "Acer%Sdfsdf"
```

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:
>
> **%** matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>
> **_** matches exactly one character.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

You can use:

```
$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '%', trim($name));
```

to convert all whitespaces to wildcards.